# Ajax async get request in Riotjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, riot.js

I cant get my Code to work with async get requests.
I want to load the JSON Objects which I get through a GET request in a Table in my File todo.tag.html.
My Problem is how can i pass the parameters. I want to pass the parameters to my riot tag but i dont know how. I tried it with each="{ allTodos() }" in my tag. This method actually works if i set async:false but not with async true.
allTodos is the method which gets the JSON objects. Anyone know what i can do?
This is my (simplified) Code
index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheet.css">
  <script src="./jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

        <script src="js/riot+compiler.min.js"></script>
        <script type="riot/tag" src="todo-form.tag.html"></script>
        <script type="riot/tag" src="todo.tag.html"></script>
    </script>
    <script>riot.mount('todoForm');</script>
                        <form>
                         <todo-form><todo-form>
                        <form>
</body>
</html>
```

todo.tag.html:

```
<todo>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" checked={ done }> { title }</label> </td>
    <td><p>{ due_date } <button type="button">Delete</button></p></td>
  </tr>

</table>


</todo>
```

todo-form.tag.html

```
<todo-form>


    <fieldset class="Issues">
        <legend>Issues</legend>
        <ul>
            <todo each="{ allTodos() }"> </todo> // This here is the problem
        </ul>
    </fieldset>


    <script>

        // return all todos
        allTodos(){
        var test = [];

        var url = 'http://myurl.com/projects'; //random adress

         $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                test = data;
                }
                });

        return test;
        }
    </script>

</todo-form>
```

Thats how my JSON objects look

```
[
  {

    "done": true,
    "title": "tests",
    "due_date": "2016-11-20T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
 {

    "done": true,
    "title": "tests2",
    "due_date": "2016-11-20T23:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tag communication you can send parameters in the tag and then in the child use the opts object. (In case you need it, here is a tutorial about tag communication http://vitomd.com/blog/coding/tag-communication-in-riot-js-part-1/)

Here is a sample (removing the async functionality as that is another problem)
As you can see I used 'todo in todos' to get a reference for the current record and then I pass a parameter called t with the record.

```
<todo each="{ todo in todos }" t={todo} > </todo>
```

Then in the todo tag I access the records using opts and t that is the parameter.

```
{ opts.t.due_date }
```

Also I used on('mount') that it will execute when mounting the tag, and this.update() to force an update. and self= this to maintain the context

```
var self = this
this.todos = []
this.on('mount', function(){
  self.todos = self.allTodos()
  self.update()
})
```

Here is the simplified code

```
<todo-form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Issues</legend>
    <ul>
      <todo each="{ todo in todos }" t={todo} > </todo>
    </ul> 
  </fieldset>

  <script>
    var self = this
    this.todos = []
    this.on('mount', function(){
      self.todos = self.allTodos()
      self.update()
    })
    allTodos(){
      var test = [{done:'true', due_date:'11', title:'the title'}, {done:'true', due_date:'11', title:'the title'}]
      return test
    }
  </script>
</todo-form>

<todo>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label><input type="checkbox" checked={ opts.t.done }> { opts.t.title }</label> </td>
      <td><p>{ opts.t.due_date } <button type="button">Delete</button></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</todo>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/PqLFIduigsOYd2XQ5LWv?p=preview

And about the async function I think that you can call self.update() in the success callback function to rerender the todos and just assign the data to
self.todos = data

```
var self = this
allTodos(){
  var url = 'http://myurl.com/projects'; //random adress
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
          self.todos = data
          self.update()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ty very much that solves it for me. Another thing how can i save the parameter { opts.t } into an array? I always get an undefined.

Comment: opts.t is not an array it's a single object. or do you mean push into an array? like var ts=[];  ts.push(t) ? or what do you mean exactly? you can create a new question with details so I can give a proper answer

Comment: Sorry i described it badly. But push(t) is what i wanted. Thanks